# How to change application pool settings on IIS web servers using powershell scripts?

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, iis, scripting

I have app pools on the IIS web server with settings that I have been able to get out in a CSV file but I have a need to change some settings based on that CSV file extracted previously.

How do I configure the settings with powershell scripts without going from server to server? Here is a sneak peak of the script I have written:

```
$IISInstalled = (Get-WindowsFeature -Name "Web-Server").installed
If ($IISInstalled -ieq $false){
Write-Output "IIS not installed"
exit
}

Import-Module webadministration
$hostname = hostname
$allapppools = (Set-Item IIS:\AppPools\).name
$path = "c:\appsettings\"
if(!(test-path $path))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -path $path
}

$allapppools | ForEach-Object($_) {
$apppool=Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$_ 
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member Hostname $hostname
$obj | Add-Member AppPoolName $apppool.Name
$obj | Add-Member .NETCLRVer $apppool.ManagedRuntimeVersion
$obj | Add-Member 32-bit $apppool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64
$obj | Add-Member ManagedPipeline $apppool.ManagedPipelineMode
$obj | Add-Member QueueLength $apppool.QueueLength
$obj | Add-Member StartupMode $apppool.StartMode
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestarttime $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value '0.23:00:00' 
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestartHours $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time.Hours -Value '23'
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestartDays $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time.Days -Value '0'
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestartMinutes $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time.Minutes -Value '0'
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestartTotalHours $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time.TotalHours -Value '23'
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestartTotalMinutes $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time.TotalMinutes -Value '1380'
$obj | Add-Member recycling-periodicRestartTotalDays $apppool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time.TotalDays -Value '0.958333'
$obj | Add-Member ItemXPath $apppool.ItemXPath
$obj | Add-Member PSPath $apppool.PSPath
$obj | Add-Member PSParentPath $apppool.PSParentPath
$obj | Add-Member PSChildName $apppool.PSChildName
$obj | Add-Member PSDrive-Root $apppool.PSDrive.Root
$obj | export-csv \\w2-cmn-util02\Reports\app-pool-azure-20210729.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
 
}
```

I understand I might have to change the scripts to effect changes on the server but I do not know how this should be done, please I'd need some help. Could someone advice on the working way to make changes on the some pools and not all.

Thanks

Comment: From server to server? If you want to manage a few servers and keep settings in sync, learn to use PowerShell DSC, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/quickstarts/website-quickstart?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: @LexLi All I want to do is change settings on my app pools for a number of them. I understand I'd need to do a setitemproperty but I need to be sure of how to do it from the scripts. Because what I do is after writing the scripts, I'd run it against the servers for the change to be effected. I need insight on how to change the short script above to change settings rather than "getting" them

Comment: There are many settings in the App pool. If you don't specify what to modify, it is difficult for others to give you sample scripts. I suggest you refer to [this](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-iis-2/) to learn how to use powershell.

Comment: @BruceZhang Noted with thanks! I would attach what I wrote if you could go over them and point out a possible error?

Comment: @BruceZhang Please look up the changes in the question

Comment: If you need a sample script, please specify the modifications you want to make. In addition, I think the best check is to run it directly. All the changes take effect is the best result.